# Vector Education

Tags: math, vector

Does anyone know where I could get a rundown of the vector math I'd need in order to program a raytracer? I could use a refresher of linear algebra and multivar calc since it's been a few years since I've taken those classes.

Comment: You can get a book on linear algebra at any Barnes and Noble or Borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear algebra is wonderful, and certainly appropriate here, but vectors in 3D space are a subset of general vector spaces.

I think something like [Vector Math Tutorial for 3D Computer Graphics](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vectorIndex.html) looks more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Good linear algebra books are terse at best, and would probably be overkill. A good 3D programming textbook might be more to the point. They'll have enough theory to get you through the math, and enough application to get you through the code.

There are plenty of free, online courses around. Some are specifically for [3D graphics programming](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vectorIndex.html). You might also take a look at [NeHe's OpenGL tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/).

If your brave, you could even look through the [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/) source.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i liked this book when i taught a computer graphics course: http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/MathCG/

3D Computer Graphics:
A Mathematical Introduction with OpenGL
Author: Samuel R. Buss

This is the homepage for the book 3D Computer Graphics: A mathematical approach with OpenGL, by Sam Buss, Cambridge University Press, 2003.   This book provides a mathematical introduction to 3D Computer Graphics at the advanced undergraduate or introductory graduate level.

```
* Table of contents:  HTML  or more complete contents as PDF.  (Pagination has changed for the actual version.)
* Sample OpenGL programs
* Ray Trace software.  Release 3 is now the standard version.  NEW: Supports .NFF and .OBJ files.  Uses kd-tree acceleration.
* Figures from the book. All figures in postscript and PDF formats.
* Errata page.   List of known errata.   Please email new errata to me at sbuss@ucsd.edu.
```